# getting data from EditText

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a simple android application which contains a EditText and a Button . User will enter his data and this application will show him the data as a Toast.

Now The problem I am facing is , whenever button is pressed by user it's just showing a blank toast.Here is my code

```
 EditText et;
String data;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bsave=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bsave);
    et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    data=et.getText().toString();



    bsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.v("EditText",et.getText().toString());
            Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondAct.class);
            in.putExtra("DATA", data);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }
    });
}
```

please help me . Thanks in Advance!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do like

```
 bsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        data=et.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

in button `onClick(...)`

Comment: @kumarkundan becoz at `data=et.getText().toString()` `et.getText().toString()=""` becoz you have no data in `et`

Answer (score 3):

You are calling gettext() in oncreate(),when there is no text at all in editbox.. So your log inside onClick() will show data but toast will never show any thing with this code as variable data is ""..

Answer (score 1):

As shown above you need to save the data in the EditText inside of the Button's on click listener. As your code is now as soon as the edit text is created the text is being saved into the data variable, but you want it to set as soon as the button is clicked.